# Not able to to do set element insertion inside constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

I am getting compilation error while inserting values inside constructor Monitor counstructor.
Could you suggest what could be approach for the same as I need to populate this
vector during class instantiation. It works fine with below approach but I don't want to populate the vector separately.

```
   vect1.insert( make_pair(10,20) );
   vect1.insert( make_pair(30,49) );
   vect1.insert( make_pair(50,60) );
   vect1.insert( make_pair(70,80) );
```

### below is the code snippet

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include<algorithm>
  #include<memory>
  #include <set>
  using namespace std;
  class Monitor
  {
  public:
  virtual ~Monitor() = default;
  explicit Monitor(
  const set< pair <double,double> > &vect1
  )
  {  

     for (auto &itr : vect1 ) 
      { 
         std::cout<<"value1 ="<<itr.first<<endl;
         std::cout<<"value2="<<itr.second<<endl;
      }       
  }

 };

int main()
{  set< pair <double,double> > vect1;
   Monitor obj (vect1.insert( make_pair(10,20) ));

 return 0;   
}
```

### compilation error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Monitor::Monitor(std::pair >, bool>)’
    Monitor obj (vect1.insert( make_pair(10,20) ));
```

Comment: using comma operator? `Monitor obj ((vect1.insert( make_pair(10,20) ), vect1));` ?

Comment: As i mentioned , during construction of object insertion should have happened. So no need here to populate the vector and pass to the object.

Comment: @max66 : you mean to say extra parameter needs to be passed as vector.

Comment: Sorry but isn't clear to me what do you want. You want a `Monitor` constructor that receive the values or you want a constructor that receive a vector that is populated inside the construction call?

Comment: Thanks max66, it works for me. I wanted to have constructor that recieve a vector that is populated inside the constructor call.

Comment: There is no vector in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor of `std::set`:

```
Monitor obj({{10,20}, {30,49}, {50,60}, {70,80}});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to have constructor that recieve a vector that is populated inside the constructor call.

If the vector (or set or whichever) can be a temporary, you can simply create and populate it inside the construction; something as

```
Monitor obj1{{{10.0, 20.0}, {30.0, 49.0}, {50.0, 60.0}}};
```

otherwise, if the set must be defined before (as in your example), the solution I see is use the comma operator to populate the set and discard the resulting iterators

```
std::set<std::pair<double,double>> vect1;

// ..........V  <-- observe the parentheses
Monitor obj2{(vect1.insert({10.0, 20.0}), // insert value and discard iterator
              vect1.insert({30.0, 49.0}), // insert value and discard iterator
              vect1.insert({50.0, 60.0}), // insert value and discard iterator
              vect1)}; // pass the populated vect1 to constructor
// ................^  <-- closing parentheses
```

Answer (score 1):

return type by [set::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) is not matching argument of the constructor `Monitor(const set< pair <double,double>>&)` instead pass the `set` something like below,

```
int main()
{
    set< pair <double, double> > vect1;
    vect1.insert(make_pair(10, 20));
    Monitor obj(vect1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  Monitor obj (vect1.insert( make_pair(10,20) ));
> ```

[`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) returns a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, not a `std::set<std::pair<double,double>>` which is expected by the user defined constructor of `Monitor`.

According to the user defined `Monitor` constructor, you need to pass a `std::set` as an argument. To do so, you can simply pass the `std::pair` objects to the constructor of `std::set`:

```
Monitor obj({{10,20}, {11,21} /*, ...*/});
```